# lose weight for MobileFirst Platform exported apps

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

While developing with IBM MobileFirst studio I've found that after building iOS/Android environment and generated native projects, even a blank app (e.g a quite simple Hello World Android app which do not use any native functionality),  will take size more than 4Mb which is much larger than a *real* native exported Android apk file.

So are there any *unused* resources that can be deleted or other things we can do so that we can lose weight in the final exported apps?

Another detail, the `classes.dex` file inside the 'blank HelloWorld'apk file seems larger than a common apk file (4Mb size).

Comment: Which MobileFirst Platform version, 6.3 or 7.0...

Comment: @IdanAdar Im using 7.0

Answer (score 0):

- Starting MFP 7.0 you can now minify and concatenate mobile environments. This means that in addition to added security, by reducing the amount of files and contents of files, it can help - to some degree - with the filesize of the application.

  [Read more about application build settings](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_optimizing_apps_build_settings.html?lang=en)
- MFPF 7 supports by default many more hardware architectures. This support is required if you intend on using features such as JSONStore and others. The files adding this support are located at your-app\android\native\libs (arm64-v8a, armabi, armabi-v7a, mips, mips64, x86, x86-64). So if you know you're not using JSONStore for example, see if removing some or all of these files helps you. But also do a regression test in general to make sure that the app continues to work as required. I could be wrong about the scope of these files - which add 3.4MB on disk.