# How to reduce a Mobilefirst apk size

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Im working in a mobilefirst hybrid app and our apk has almost 13mb file size, is there any and our common folder only has 2mb (with jquery mobile not minimize).

Im seeing a lot of .so in our apk with aprox. 1mb:

```
assets/icudt46l.zip
assets/featurelibs/armeabi/libcrypto.so.1.0.0.so
assets/featurelibs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.so.1.0.0.so
assets/featurelibs/x86/libcrypto.so.1.0.0.so
and like twenty .so in the /lib folder
```

Is there any way to reduce the mobilefirst apks size, because our customers are working on remote locations and they dont have a lot of bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here: [lose weight for MobileFirst Platform exported apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640953/lose-weight-for-mobilefirst-platform-exported-apps)

> - Starting MFP 7.0 you can now minify and concatenate mobile environments. This means that in addition to added security, by
>     reducing the amount of files and contents of files, it can help - to
>     some degree - with the filesize of the application.
>
>   [Read more about application build settings](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_optimizing_apps_build_settings.html?lang=en)
> - MFPF 7 supports by default many more hardware architectures. This support is required if you intend on using features such as JSONStore
>     and others. The files adding this support are located at
>     your-app\android\native\libs (arm64-v8a, armabi, armabi-v7a, mips,
>     mips64, x86, x86-64). So if you know you're not using JSONStore for
>     example, see if removing some or all of these files helps you. But
>     also do a regression test in general to make sure that the app
>     continues to work as required. I could be wrong about the scope of
>     these files - which add 3.4MB on disk.

Comment: im using mf 6.3 with json store and push notifications